# List of required artifacts to upload to server for Electron-Builder Autoupdate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I've been trying to find a definitive list of the files I need to host on my update server for updates to work. There doesn't seem to be a concrete answer anywhere and the question has gone unanswered on their issue tracker.

Is `win-unpacked` folder, or do I only need the `.exe`, the `.yml` and the `.exe.blockmap` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only required artifacts appear to be the installer executable and the `latest.yml` or equivalent.

I'm unsure what the minimum required for differential downloads is. They definitely require the `.blockmap` file and may also require uploading the `win-unpacked` folder (on Windows) but I'm not entirely sure.